# Azure SQL as Publisher

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I want to replicate data on PaaS Azure SQL to IaaS SQL Server Instance. Can I use SQL Serer Replication (Not Azure Geo Replication) to replicate data from Azure SQL to SQL server Instance onPremises/IaaS Platform. Here Azure SQL will act as a publisher as well as distributor whereas onPremises/IaaS SQL Server Instance act as subscriber. I know you can replicate data from OnPremisis to Azure SQL but I want other way around.

Thanks for the Anticipation.

Thanks and Regards,
DK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of SQL Data Sync. To learn how to setup and configure it, please use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) article.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I need to use this to replicate data from Azure SQL to on Premises SQL Server and Costume SQL Server Instance on Cloud VM as well?

Comment: The SQL Azure database will be a hub database the other databases will be member databases. It is bi-directional data synchronization.

Comment: What If I only use Member databases for Reporting purpose. Then I dont think so it gonna be bidirectional. It will be uni directional from Azure SQL (Hub) to Member Databases (MS SQL onPrimises or hosted on IaaS VM). Correct me If I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You can perfectly use the member database for read-only workloads as reporting purposes.